# Jenkins Junit Reporter unable to locate xml file?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver-io

System: Macbook Pro

Currently I'm running Jenkins on my macbook pro but it seems that Jenkins Junit report post actions plugin is unable to locate my .xml reports, once my WebdriverIo framework has executed my test scripts.

The report xml file is being generated, including triggering of the tests, it seems that Jenkins is unable to locate my JUnit reports folder?
[image]

Comment: Any progress on this Sam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More importantly... what are you seeing in the `Test Result` view? You should be seeing something like this:

[image]

Let's isolate the problem!

1. The **JUnit reporter** setup in `wdio.conf.js` file;
2. **Post-build Actions** setup for the **JUnit reporter** (*in Jenkins*);
3. Verify the build `Workspace` (*in Jenkins, post test-run*);
4. Others

### 1.

( My **JUnit Reporter** `wdio.conf.js` config )

```
reporters: ['junit'],
reporterOptions: {
    'junit': {
        outputDir: './reports',
        outputFileFormat: function(opts) {
            return `results-webdriverio.${process.env.USER}.${opts.cid}.xml`;
        }
    }
}
```

### 2.

( My setup for **JUnit Reporter** )

[image]

Most likely you have an issue with the path to the JUnit `.xml`. Use relative paths! (e.g: `reports/*.xml`, `reports/**/*.xml`, etc.).

> **Note:** Basedir of the fileset is the workspace root.

### 3.

Check your build `Workspace` and see if the `.xml` report has indeed been generated and is residing in your path (e.g: in the `/reports` folder).

**If not**, then I'd go into the `Console` section and start looking into your build logs to see where the issue is.

**!Note:** I get the same Jenkins input errors (*red notifications*), but as far as I know, I have been always getting them. The `.xml` reports still get evaluated by the JUnit plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What's the root of your workspace?

If it's `\Users\joeblogs\Desktop\webdriverio2\`, then `reports\junit-result\*.xml` would be enough.

It seems like you are trying to provide a absolute path, maybe try delete the first two `**` before `\Users`.